# How to check if a constructor class has already been pushed

Tags: javascript

I have a function that push a new constructor class, but I only want it to push a new one when there isn't one present.

Right now my code is basicly like this:

```
class InterSpot {
  constructor(game){
    this.game = game;
    this.x = 100;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.markedForDeletion = false;
    this.lives = 5;
    this.score = this.lives;
  }
  update(){
    this.x += this.speedX;
    if (this.x + this.width < 0) this.markedForDeletion = true;
  }
  draw(context){
    context.fillStyle = 'blue';
    context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    context.font = '20px Helvetica';
    context.fillText(this.lives, this.x, this.y);
  }
}
        class Intro extends InterSpot {
            constructor(game){
                super(game);
                this.width = 228 * 0.2; // Largeur d'une frame de l'ennemi
                this.height = 169 * 0.2; // Hauteur d'une frame de l'ennemi
                this.y = 100;
                //this.y = Math.random() * (this.game.height * 0.9 - this.height);
            }
        }

addInteractionSpot(){
  if (!this.interactionSpot.includes(Intro)) {
    this.interactionSpot.push(new Intro(this));
      console.log(this.interactionSpot);
      console.log(this.interactionSpot.includes(Intro));
    }
}
```

I tried with indexof, includes and typeof, but nothing worked. I just want to detect if there already is a constructor class of name 'Intro' on screen, so that if a button is pressed it disapear for 5 seconds than reapear.

Comment: What is `this.interactionSpot`, you never declare it

Comment: What do you mean by "*push a new constructor class*"?

Comment: Ah, sorry, @Konrad, I forgot to put when I declare this.interactionSpot in my question, but it is declared in my local code. I just didn't want to put the 2182 lines of code in the question. Sorry about forgetting to put the declaration in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `instanceof` against each item in the array:

```js
class Intro {}

let interactionSpot = [new Intro()]

console.log(interactionSpot.some(i=>i instanceof Intro))
```

Therefore, in your code, the line would be:

```js
if (!this.interactionSpot.some(i=>i instanceof Intro))
```